# Bootstrap Grid System doesn't consist 12 columns?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm trying to build a row like col-md-2 | col-md-8 | col-md-2 and it should be looking like following screenshot.

[image]

But mine actually is being like this. The last column is supposed to be in the same line right?

[image]

I don't have any idea since I'm new to CSS and Bootstraps thing. What's wrong with my code?

```
<div class="container" ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="myController">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 customDiv"></div>
        <div class="col-md-8 customDiv"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2 customDiv">
            <p class="bottom">
                Glory glory Man united, <br>
                Glory glory Man united, <br>
                Glory glory Man united, <br>
                As the reds go marching up up up!
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

main.css

```
.customDiv{
    margin: 3px;
    min-height: 300px;
    background-color: silver;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: large;
    text-align: start;
}
```

style tag

```
<style>
            body {
                padding-top: 50px;
                padding-bottom: 20px;
                background: url('img/login background.jpg');
                background-size: cover;
                background-repeat:no-repeat;
                display: compact;
            }


        </style>
```

Comment: Make sure that all elements have `box-sizing: border-box;`.

Comment: Can you share your `CSS` code? I'm pretty sure it's happening because of some extra `CSS` added by you, I can see **customDiv** class. Please share more codes.

Comment: could not replicate your issue, BOOTPLY: https://www.bootply.com/nu6g1aHp4q - its probably some other CSS

Comment: edited my question

Comment: its your `margin: 3px` in `.customDiv{ ...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the class ".customDiv". It looks like you have margins in-between each col. It is perhaps best to place a second div within the .col with your custom css.

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="customDiv">
        <p>text here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

your `margin: 3px` in `.customDiv{}` does it.
what you want to do is nest it in bootstrap columns and let it do your **padding** not margin.

```
<div class="container" ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="myController">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="col-md-12 customDiv">123</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 ">
      <div class="col-md-12 customDiv">123</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="col-md-12 customDiv">
        <p class="bottom">
            Glory glory Man united, <br>
            Glory glory Man united, <br>
            Glory glory Man united, <br>
            As the reds go marching up up up!
        </p>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

bootply example: https://www.bootply.com/CjZJkuC2Dq